# Having a Solana program mint tokens while a user pays the fee

Tags: rust, pda, spl-token, signature, mint

I'm trying to have a Solana Anchor program mint tokens to a user's token account (so the program or its PDA should be the authority for the mint), while the owner of the token account that's receiving the tokens should pay the fee.

This is what I have right now:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token;
use anchor_spl::token::{Token, MintTo};

declare_id!("EcFTDXxknt3vRBi1pVZYN7SjZLcbHjJRAmCmjZ7Js3fd");
//token HKTPz1skkSNAC8TXJiYvPyYtMCQDHtAheCL4FrBArCDJ
//program EcFTDXxknt3vRBi1pVZYN7SjZLcbHjJRAmCmjZ7Js3fd
//account GHQMHrt4j8i6bBaVhpMCLP8uoFfWUrLZsQtWCWqSJKA6
#[program]
pub mod solana_ubi {
    use super::*;

    pub fn mint_token(ctx: Context<MintToken>,) -> Result<()> {
        // Create the MintTo struct for our context
        let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.owner.to_account_info(),
        };

        //need to make pda. see cookbook: sign a transaction with a pda.

        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        // Create the CpiContext we need for the request
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

        // Execute anchor's helper function to mint tokens
        token::mint_to(cpi_ctx, 10_000_000_000)?;

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MintToken<'info> {
    /// CHECK: This is the token that we want to mint
    #[account()]
    pub mint: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    /// CHECK: This is the token account that we want to mint tokens to
    #[account(mut)]
    pub token_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: ugh
    #[account(signer)]
    pub owner: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
```

this does mint the tokens, if I pass the mint's authority (any account holding SOL) as owner. Again for clarity: I want this program to be the mint authority for the token, but the user receiving the tokens to pay the fee. how should I change the code to make it work as described above? Please provide a code answer.

Comment: This really requires way too much code to answer, you need to look at some other tutorials first to understand how anchor constraints work and if you have more specifics issue when trying to implement it feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Is it essential that this is implemented as a Solana program? I'd lean toward just making the mint authority a wallet you control, and writing a TypeScript API that returns a (serialized) partially signed transaction with the sender as fee payer, and with one instruction to mint tokens to the user. The transaction would be signed by your wallet, which is the mint authority. The user can then sign and send the transaction and will pay the fee. Depends on your exact requirements whether that'd work for you though.

Comment: You should take a look at the following question, it provides an overview and example code to do what you’re asking. 

https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/47/how-do-i-create-an-nft-using-anchor/52#52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the Mint Authority to a PDA account of the program like this :

```
const MINTER:&str = "minter";

#[program]
pub mod token_mint_pda {
    use super::*;


    pub fn mint_token(ctx: Context, bump: u8, amount: u64) -> Result {
        // Minting the token to destination wallet with the signer as a 
        // PDA account which holds the mint authority.
        anchor_spl::token::mint_to(
            CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                anchor_spl::token::MintTo {
                    mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.destination.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                },
                &[&[
                    MINTER.as_bytes(),
                    &[bump]
                ]],
            ),
            amount,
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MintToken<'info> {
    // Init PDA Mint Account which will be used for minting tokens 
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = payer,
        seeds = [MINTER.as_ref()],
        bump,
        mint::decimals = 0,
        mint::authority = mint
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    
    // Signer who pays the fees for minting
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    
    // Associated token account of the wallet where mint token will go
    #[account(init_if_needed,
              payer = payer, 
              associated_token::mint = mint, 
              associated_token::authority = payer
    )]
    pub destination: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

To test this

```
describe("token-mint-pda", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();

  const program = anchor.workspace.TokenMintPda as Program<TokenMintPda>;

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // Generating keypair for destination address
    const destination = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

    // Airdrop some SOL to that wallet
    await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(
      await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(destination.publicKey, 10000000),
      "confirmed"
    );
    
    // Find the PDA account with the seed - Mint Account
    const [mint, bump] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [
        Buffer.from(anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("minter"))
      ],
      program.programId
    );

    // Find ATA of destination address corresponding to the mint
    const userATA = await Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
      ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      mint,
      destination.publicKey
   );


    // Let's transfer 100 tokens to destination
    let amount = new anchor.BN(100);

    // Executing the mintToken function on program
    const tx = await program.methods.mintToken(bump,amount).accounts({
      mint: mint,
      payer: destination.publicKey,
      destination: userATA,
      systemProgram:  anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      tokenProgram:spl.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      associatedTokenProgram:spl.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      rent:anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY
    }).signers([destination]).rpc();
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
  });
});
```

Comment: please annotate this code so folks who are unfamiliar can follow along more easily

Answer (score -1):

After the minting is done(Which the user pays for), you can change the authority of the mint by making a cpi call to the token program's set_authority instruction. Check for token::set_authority in the anchor_spl documentation.